# Weird write file issue on a drive with no space left on it

Tags: android, c++

We've found (different devices, different Android versions) that Android returns no errors when we're writing on an SD card with **no space left** on it!

I.e. I'm able to successfully create a new file and file write function returns OK status also, but it does not write anything actually. The real size of such file on disk stays 0 bytes.

We're using native C++ APIs.

I've tried to reproduce this on a new project on my Android 11 phone and yes - the issue is still there.

I did the following steps:

1. Create a new Native C++ project using Android Studio.
2. In its C++ code add test function and call it.
3. Launch project using Android Studio - yes, we are able to see the same behavior.

The test code I was using:

```
#include <android/log.h>

bool test()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    auto path = "/storage/150E-2D07/Download/test_1";

    FILE *f2 = nullptr;
    bool ok = true;

    std::int64_t bytesWritten = 0;

#define checkok if (!ok) goto _error

    ok = nullptr != (f2 = fopen(path, "wb"));
    checkok;
    ok = ferror(f2) == 0;
    checkok;

    for (int i = 0; ; ++i)
    {
        char a[16*1024];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); ++i)
            a[i] = std::rand()%256;

        ok = sizeof(a) == fwrite(a, 1, sizeof(a), f2);
        checkok;

        ok = ferror(f2) == 0;
        checkok;

        ok = !fflush(f2);
        checkok;

        ok = ferror(f2) == 0;
        checkok;

        bytesWritten += sizeof(a);
        if (!(i % 1000))
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "TEST", "writing.. bytes written: %f", bytesWritten/1024.0/1024.0);
    }

    return true;

    _error:
    if (f2)
        fclose(f2);

    return false;
}
```

I've also noticed that when there is no space left, `fwrite` function works much faster (we get speeds which SD card can't afford).

I've created Android 13 virtual device with 500MB emulated SD card in it. Launched my test app in it. It wrote 1.4GB of data, then I terminated it. I copied this file to my computer and found that 1st 500MB are filled with actual data and the remained contents are just zeroes. Sounds like a total bug of Android OS to me. I'm wondering how is it possible that such a critical bug still exists and it seems like no one cares about it.

Comment: What is the result of `fflush(f2)` after the `fwrite()`? I believe at least that should fail... (`fflush()` is successful if it returns 0)

Comment: You also might want to check [`ferror`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ferror/)

Comment: `fflush` returns 0 (i.e. no error). The size of the file actually increases (i.e. it's non 0 byte anymore), but it's filled with zeros, not an actual data the test function wrote to it.

Comment: A few moments later, I don't know how, its size became also the same 0 bytes.

Comment: I've tested with `ferror` (using a new name for file) - it returns 0 (i.e. no error).

Comment: I've updated my test code to use `fflush` and `ferror` also.

Comment: Yes, it's 100% reproducible that file size always becomes 0 bytes a few moments later. I.e. fflush "flushes" some fake bytes which are "removed" somehow later.

Comment: Unrelated, but can you try using C++ IO mechanisms (fstream or filesystem) and check what happens?

Comment: What is the return-status from fclose?

Comment: @HansOlsson It's never called.

Comment: That error checking is kind of mess. Unreadable, a nasty goto you could avoid (you use a loop which can be a state loop, ffs!). Until file is closed, it's size can be reported as zero. If that's a logger, were work in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280236407.

I was told that I need to call `fsync`. And yes, fsync helps and returns error.

All the other file functions never return any errors under Android in this case (including `fclose`).